# GitHub Actions unable to set up Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-actions, python-venv

I need to setup a virtual environment, and install the requirements for my Flask app.

However, an error occurs here:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
sudo python3.8 -m venv venv
```

This is the `.yml` file for my GitHub Actions.

```
name: TEST

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Setup system group
      run: |
        if [ ! $( getent group uni ) ]; then sudo addgroup --system uni; fi
        
    - name: Setup system user
      run: |
        if [[ $(getent passwd uni) = "" ]]; then sudo adduser --no-create-home --force-badname --disabled-login --disabled-password --system uni; fi
    - name: Add user user to group
      run: |
        sudo usermod -g uni uni
    
    - name: Setup base directory
      working-directory: /
      run: |
        if [ ! -d ./uni/test/app ]; then sudo mkdir -p ./uni/test/app; fi
        sudo chown uni:uni -R /uni/test
        sudo chmod 775 -R /uni/test
      
    - name: Setup log directory
      working-directory: /var/log
      run: |
        if [ ! -d ./uni/test ]; then sudo mkdir -p ./uni/test; fi
        sudo chown uni:uni -R ./uni/test
        sudo chmod 755 -R ./uni/test
      
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
        
    - name: Setup Python virtual environment
      working-directory: /uni/test/app
      run: |
        sudo apt install python3-venv
        sudo python3.8 -m venv venv
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      working-directory: /uni/test/app/venv
      run: |
        source ./bin/activate
        pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install wheel
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
        deactivate
```

What am I doing wrong here?

And is there a way I can install python3-venv inside the block below?

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Set up Python 3.8
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: 3.8
```

Comment: Hello. Please provide the error you are getting

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just tested a [simple workflow here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester19.yml) (same as below) to use the virtual env.

It doesn't seem you need the `sudo apt install python3-env` command when using the `actions/checkout` and the `setup-python` actions to create the virtual env using the `python3.8 -m venv env` command.

```yaml
on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Run Python commands
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          python3.8 -m venv env
          source env/bin/activate
          echo "VIRTUAL ENV:" $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Returned me `VIRTUAL ENV: /home/runner/work/poc-github-actions/poc-github-actions/env` on the [workflow run logs](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/4610138792?check_suite_focus=true).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved it a while ago just forgot to update this question.

Comment: One note: `source env/bin/activate` wouldn’t work on a Windows runner, because instead of `bin` the scripts are stored in the `Scripts` folder.